# Longitudinal measures mixed model in lmer in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, treatment-effect

I would like to build a mixed model using the lme4 package in R.

The study design is like this: We have measured the change in a variable over time in mice under different Diets. The mice under different diets are different, not the same. We would like to see which condition (Diet) causes a significant change in the variable compared to control diet. The structure of the data can be seen below:

```
'data.frame':   784 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ SampleID: Factor w/ 98 levels "Mice234",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Time: int  7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 7 9 ...
 $ variable   : num  NA 20.2 21.5 22.9 23 25.2 26.9 NA 19 22.2 ...
 $ Diet    : Factor w/ 9 levels "Diet1","Diet2",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 9 9 ...
```

I have built up following model with Time as a fixed effect and Diet and ID as a random effect.

```
lmer(variable ~ Time + Diet + (1 | SampleID) + (1 | Diet), data =data, REML = FALSE)
```

I ran the model and this is the output:

```
    Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: variable ~ Time + Diet + (1 | SampleID) + (1 | Diet)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 2235.4

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9157 -0.4709  0.0202  0.4695  3.8323 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 SampleID (Intercept) 2.595    1.611   
 Diet     (Intercept) 1.824    1.351   
 Residual             1.849    1.360   
Number of obs: 588, groups:  SampleID, 98; Diet, 9

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)       17.2153     1.6107  10.688
Time           0.4499     0.0147  30.606
Diet1    -0.3610     2.1598  -0.167
Diet2  -1.9533     2.1330  -0.916
Diet3            19.7461     2.1891   9.020
Diet4  -1.3082     2.1795  -0.600
Diet5  -1.5830     2.2020  -0.719
Diet6    -2.7308     2.1145  -1.291
Diet7         19.7525     2.2125   8.927
Diet8    -1.4892     2.1795  -0.683


coefs <- data.frame(coef(summary(m)))
coefs$p.z <- 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(coefs$t.value)))
coefs
                   Estimate Std..Error    t.value       p.z
(Intercept)      17.2153100  1.6107440 10.6878002 0.0000000
Time          0.4499233  0.0147007 30.6055728 0.0000000
Diet1   -0.3609887  2.1598318 -0.1671374 0.8672619
Diet2 -1.9533316  2.1329930 -0.9157703 0.3597874
Diet3           19.7460769  2.1891371  9.0200274 0.0000000
Diet4 -1.3081610  2.1795476 -0.6001984 0.5483740
Diet5 -1.5829868  2.2019821 -0.7188918 0.4722076
Diet6   -2.7307647  2.1145054 -1.2914437 0.1965499
Diet7        19.7525431  2.2125545  8.9274831 0.0000000
Diet8   -1.4891979  2.1794666 -0.6832855 0.4944265
```

Is my model correct based on my question? I can see that diet3 and diet7 have a significant effect over time on the variable, but how I could compare these two diets against the control diet (i.e. Diet2).

Comment: You do not get coefficients for Diet because you did not include it in the model.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would add time in the random effects, since **each animal will have a different pattern of evolution through time, thus having a different slope.** At the same time, I would not add the diet as random effect.

I would try the following model:

```
ml1 <- lmer(variable ~ Time * Diet + (Time | SampleID), data = data)
```

This would allow to:

- ascertain if there is an effect of Diet in the longitudal evolution of the variable;
- while taking into account that each animal may have a different slope in time.

Hope this helps

Comment: The random slopes and intercepts model has a a lot of parameters to estimate.  I would fit a serial correlation longitudinal model with no random slopes or intercepts.  See [here](https://fharrell.com/post/re).

Comment: @FrankHarrell, the random slopes model has only an extra two parameters than the random-intercept one and allows for serial correlation. In fact, random effects are very powerful for longitudinal data, allowing you to model the serial correlations flexibly.

Comment: Dimitris that’s not quite right.  These models can be unstable and convergence can be difficult because they are estimating 2cn parameters not 2 parameters, where n is the number of animals and c is some number between 0 and 1.  If the variance of the random intercepts or the random slopes is not tiny then c is closer to 1.  When you solve for the effective number of parameters estimated (2cn) you’ll often be surprised.  c is a function of the two variances.

Comment: Random effects models are most needed when one wants to estimate trajectories of individual animals.  If the interest is only in group-level effects then random effects models can be an overkill.  In addition, the correlation pattern induced by random slopes models is very hard to justify when compared to observed correlation patterns in the raw data.

Comment: @FrankHarell What you say about the extra number of parameters to be estimated is new for me. I have always thought there would be just two additional parameters, a variance of the random time effect and the covariance of the random time and random intercept. If e.g. you would compare the deviances of (1) a model with only a random intercept and (2) a model with random intercept and random time effect, the number nr. of degrees of freedom would be 2, pointing to the two extra parameters. Why is this then? Or to put it different: where do the 2n extra (given that c=1 say) parameters come from?